# IBM MQ: parallel consumption with multiple consumers

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I work with IBM MQ queue and I try to consume messages in multiple consumers in parallel.
I created 10 consumers and try to fetch batch of 10 messages calling `consumer.receive()` on each consumer in 10 threads. I have quite a high ping value between MQ host and client and when I run my app I see something like in my log

```
consumer 1 called receive
consumer 2 called receive 
consumer 3 called receive
...
consumer 1 read the message
<50 ms later>
consumer 2 read the message
<50 ms later>
consumer 3 read the message
```

so it looks like reading messages one-by-one, not in parallel, while receive() was called in parallel in several threads and I expected something like

```
consumer 1 called receive
consumer 2 called receive 
consumer 3 called receive
<50 ms later>
consumer 1 read the message
consumer 2 read the message
consumer 3 read the message
```

Why are my expectations wrong? Does IBM MQ allows to have any benefits of multiple consumers using one queue or some configuration is required.

Thanks.

Comment: What is SHARECNV set to on the SVRCONN channel you connect to?  I would suggest you have the MQ admin set it to 1, the default is 10.  Multiple threads will use the same TCP connection up to the SHARECNV  value which is the max.  Setting it to 1 will force it to use a separate TCP connection per thread.

Comment: What is the depth of the input queue... if there are no messages on the queue - it will take a long time! to get one.   Try it with more than 10 messages on the queue.

Comment: IBM MQ has a concept of "hot getter/consumer". It will feed the next message to the same consumer if that consumer is back waiting for a message.

Comment: @colinpaice for my testing I stopped consumer, generated hundred of messages and started it, to make sure that there is a backlog for several full batches.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks, I'll try to check - it is external vendor mq instance, so not a quick thing to verify. But is my understanding correct, that if default value is 10, than for 20 consumers I should see some benefits, comparing to 1 receive call in single thread?

Comment: @dbf "than for 20 consumers I should see some benefits" -  No. IBM has tuned MQ and now 1 will give you the best performance. IBM just won't change the default from 10 to 1.

Comment: You can also use a CCDT on the client side and set SHARECNV(1) on the CLNTCONN, MQ will negotiate to the lowest value.

Comment: @JoshMc SHARECNV=1 is set on server

Comment: It was already set or updated?

Comment: @JoshMc yes, it was set already before I started any tests

Comment: Then in not sure.   I see no reason it should take 50ms between each receive.  Are you sure it is executing threads in parallel and not having some client side limitation?